# Fetch object which contains array of other objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have Item class and Package class which extends Item. The only field that is added in Package class is $ingredients which I would like to be an array of Item objects. I am pretty new to zend/doctrine, I use tutorials to learn it.

I was able to learn how to fetch objects form tables no problem, but I don't really know how I can fetch Package object which contains array of Item object with their quantity. How this should be done?

Item class:

```
class Item {
protected $item_id,
/* @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $name
/* @Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2) */
protected $price
}
```

item table:

```
item_id int,
name varchar(100),
price decimal(10,2)
```

Package class:

```
Class Package extends Item
{
protected $ingredients; // This field should be an array of Item objects.
}
```

item_ingredient table (contains item-ingredient relation):

```
item_id int,
ingredient_id int,
quantity int
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup relationship between entity classes. Go through the doctrine tutorial for setting up the relationships between entities.

Basically Package has a Many to one relationship with Item and it can be setup only through proper annotations.